# Binding declaration namespace "http://annox.dev.java.net" will be ignored because it is not designated by the jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes attribute

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I am trying to generate Java classes from xsd by using jaxb2 maven plugin.

While generating the classes it gives the following exception:

> SAXParseException Binding declaration namespace
>   "http://annox.dev.java.net" will be ignored because it is not
>   designated by the jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes attribute.

This is the xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.emc.com/concerto/v2.0"
           xmlns:val="http://annox.dev.java.net/javax.validation.constraints"
           xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.emc.com/concerto/v2.0" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="2.0">
    <xs:complexType name="ValueType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
                Represents the value in a key-value pair.
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="vType" type="xs:string" use="required">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation source="modifiable">always</xs:documentation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
                            Value type. Could be String, Number, DateTime or Boolean.
                        </xs:documentation>
                        <xs:documentation source="required">true</xs:documentation>
                        <xs:appinfo>
                            <annox:annotate target="field">
                                <val:NotNull/>
                            </annox:annotate>
                        </xs:appinfo>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:attribute>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the namespace prefix of your namespace `http://annox.dev.java.net` to the attribute `jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes`, as the error message says:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.emc.com/concerto/v2.0"
           xmlns:val="http://annox.dev.java.net/javax.validation.constraints"
           xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
           jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="annox"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://www.emc.com/concerto/v2.0"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           version="2.0">
```

Comment: Is there any other way that can solve this problem? Because i have around 120 xsds that are in the same format.

Comment: Yes there is an other way : remove xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net" from your xsd since you are not  using it. I think this annox namespace is only used in your binding file.

Comment: @Tristan If you look at the XSD that Salih posted, you see that it does contain an `<annox:annotate>` element. So the namespace *is* used in his XSDs.